# How can I show icons in push notification?

Tags: php, ionic4, push, angular8

Getting an issue with icons in the **push notification**.

I am using PHP to send **push notification** to android app, and the android app I have created using **Ionic 4** and **Angular 8**

Below is the PHP Code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", true);

// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'xyz' );

$registrationIds = array("");

$_POST['title'] = "Title goes here.";
$_POST['subtitle'] = " ";
$_POST['ticket_text'] = " ";
$_POST['message'] = "Write here your message.";

// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => $_POST['message'],
    'title'     => $_POST['title'],
    'subtitle'  => $_POST['subtitle'],
    'tickerText' => $_POST['ticket_text'],
    'vibrate' => 1,
    'alert'=> 'true',
    'badge'=> true,
    'sound'=> 'true',
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'              => $msg
);
$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
exit;
```

The **notification** looks like the below image, there it shows the icon in **Gray color**, I want to show there my app icon.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The icon should be stored in your resources folders of the android app. Then you in the largeIcon or smallIcon you send the name of the file.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/r3xeYpG
Do I have to keep that filename in config.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

```
<platform name="android">
 ... 
<resource-file src="locales/android/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
 <resource-file src="locales/android/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
 <resource-file src="locales/android/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
 <resource-file src="locales/android/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" /> 
<resource-file src="locales/android/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" /> 
<!-- Uncomment if you have added a large icon. --> 
<!--- <resource-file src="locales/android/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_onesignal_large_icon_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_onesignal_large_icon_default.png" /> ---> 
</platform>
```

I know you not using onesignal, but its the same way to store the image in android, so change the ic_stat_onesignal_default.png to the name needed.

```
https://medium.com/@senning/push-notifications-with-ionic-and-cordova-plugin-firebase-ab0c0cad3cc0
```

And here is a link on how exactly you can do it to be more clear since here he is using firebase not onesignal and this could be clearer for you.